# How and where does the Facade class property $app get set?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I have done a lot of digging and cannot seem to see where or how the `$app` property is set in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`

I am aware all Facades are set in `config/app.php` and auto loaded using the `Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader` however i can see the auto load and class_alias, I however cannot see where the main `$app` is passed or injected?

Comment: The property is static. Look for `static::$app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it there is a `setFacadeApplication( $app )` method which is set on the initialization of the Laravel App.